# In Mass Effect 3, I did not get a choice of game mode; is it because I imported a ME2 character?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-3

I just started a new game in Mass Effect 3, on the Xbox 360, by importing my existing ME2 character.

I have just witnessed the attack on the council at the very start, and now just got to the point where I can bring up the in-game menu.

I have not yet seen a choice of game mode (i.e. action, role playing, or story), as advertised for the game.

Was that choice made for me when I imported? If so, what am I actually playing? I'm hoping role playing (which was my intent), but how can I verify this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you import an ME2 character you automatically use the roleplaying mode (the one with combat *and* dialog choices), only if you create a new character do you get the choice in the beginning. The roleplaying mode is the one closest to how the previous Mass Effect games worked, so the game assumes that players that import a character would like to play that mode.

Answer (score 21):

There aren't really game modes per-se. Rather, they are just presets for two settings: "Combat Difficulty" and "Conversation Mode".

- **Action:** No Decisions, Normal Difficulty
- **Role Playing:** Full Decisions, Normal Difficulty
- **Story:** Full Decisions, Narrative Difficulty

The default for an imported character is Role Playing. However, you can change both these options at any time from the "Narrative" and "Gameplay" sections of the options menu.

Note that if you want to get the Insanity achievement, you will have to use the options menu to change the difficulty to Insanity before leaving Earth.

Comment: I like this answer better.  It fully explains the mechanics between the "game mode" choices, and covers the fact that you *can* change your mind later.  Having only thus far played an imported character, I wasn't aware that there were bundled "game mode" options for new players.  But I have noticed the "Combat Difficulty" and "Conversation Mode" options, and really appreciate the logic behind them.