# Can I change the story mode when I import a character?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If I finish the game on Story mode then import that character into a new game, can I select a different mode like Action or Roleplaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import a character, you automatically switch in Role-Playing mode.
The same kind of question was asked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54210/in-mass-effect-3-i-did-not-get-a-choice-of-game-mode-is-it-because-i-imported). You can look at it to have more info.